# Lock a raycast Ray axis in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch, wordsearch

I'm creating a word search like game.

But i'm having trouble to correctly select letters.

I use raycast as below:

```
            Ray ray;
            RaycastHit hit;
            GameObject current;

            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10f, Color.green);

            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider.tag == "tile")
                {
                    add this letter;
                }
            }
```

it's working, but i want to lock the axis of the ray when the user is moving in a direction.

For example, when the user touch the screen, and starts moving to the right, the ray is lock on the x axis.

Or if the user touch the screen and moves up, it locks the ray on the y axis.

Any help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You basically want this to work as a text selector? (Like when you left-click and drag over text, e.g. here in the browser, it gets highlighted, working horizontally and vertically? Vertically without line selection, just the exact column?)

Comment: ...if so, you're not axis locking the *raycast* but rather using the axis lock as a modification on the input being used to generate the ray being cast.

Comment: @GunnarB. yes i want to do this, and also add diagonal axis so i have 8 direction axis.

Comment: I don't you would do this using raycast, but instead the touch position and `Touch.phase`. Have a look at this (the code is maybe a bit outdated at some points, but I think you can get some clues from it): http://rengelbert.com/blog/2015/10/11/building-a-word-game-in-unity/

Comment: @GunnarB. thanks for the link, i saw it last time, and i downloaded the project files, and i have the same issue, you can select words in any directions. what i want is when the user start to select into the x axis, it locks the raycast on that axis.

Comment: Thats just a matter of adding some logic to the `HandleTouchMove` function in that code. You can grab the start position in `HandleTouchDown`, calculate the direction you are dragging in in `HandleTouchMove` (at the beginning of the dragging) and then keep that direction and ignore others (so basically ignore the other if statements in `HandleTouchMove`).

Comment: @GunnarB. thanks, i will try to do that. Just to be more accurate, i would like to create the same kind of selection as this [link](http://www.freewordsearches.net/wordsearch/natural-selection-word-search)

Comment: In that case it might be a bit more like drawing a line (not actually, but for the logic) from the start point to the mouse position and matching that to one of the axis with an angle threshold. Say, if the line would be to the top right from where you start and within like a +-10° range of 45° you select diagonally to the top right. (With horizontal axis to the right being the reference axis. Also, the angle has to be adjusted based on the shape of the tiles, 45° for up right direction would be with square tiles.)

Comment: @GunnarB. well the issue here is that the touch inputs are in the update method, so it's hard to define a start position.

Comment: You can use the touch phases for this. On touch begin, snap the mouse position (or rather the closest tiles center). Have a look at this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html